# unable to get my frontend container to communicate with my backend container with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, vuejs3

I have done this many times but for some reason I am not able to get my containers to communicate.

Even when I try to curl from the frontend I cannot connect!

example:

```
/etc/nginx # curl http://localhost:8081/v1/test
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8081 after 0 ms: Connection refused
/etc/nginx #

bb36725aa567   vue-golang-grpc-base-client     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 minutes ago    Up 3 minutes    80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp       vue-golang-grpc-base-client-1
8d9fa96e0e67   vue-golang-grpc-base-api        "./main"                 15 minutes ago   Up 15 minutes   0.0.0.0:8081-8082->8081-8082/tcp   vue-golang-grpc-base-api-1
```

My nginx file looks like

```
 upstream api {
    server ${API_HOST}:8081;
 }

 server {
     server_name localhost example.com www.example.com;
     listen 8080;

     root /usr/share/nginx/html;

     access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

     location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ico|woff|woff2|ttf)$ {
         expires 1y;
         add_header Cache-Control "public";
         access_log off;
     }

     location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
     }

     location ~ ^/(api)/ {
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

         proxy_redirect off;
         proxy_pass http://api;

         add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
         expires off;
     }

 }
```

I am using Vue.js 3 with typescript and created a custom url handler because I am not using webpack.

```
export class EnvironmentHelper {
    public static get isDevelopment(): boolean {
        return process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
    }

    public static get isProduction(): boolean {
        return process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
    }

    public get baseUrl(): string {
        if (EnvironmentHelper.isDevelopment) {
            return "http://localhost:8081"
        }
        if (EnvironmentHelper.isProduction) {
            return "http://localhost:8080/"
        }
        
        return "/";
    }
}
```

then I have a `.env` file

```
NODE_ENV=development
API_HOST=localhost
```

and am using axios

```
const url = new EnvironmentHelper()

export const api = {

    async getTest() {
        try{
            return await grpcClient.get<TestResponse>(url + "v1/test")
```

---

```
/etc/nginx # echo $API_HOST
localhost
```

then I build the image using docker compose

```
version: '3.0'
services:
    api:
        build:
            context: ./api
        ports:
            - "8082:8082" # gRPC
            - "8081:8081" # gRPC Gateway
        networks:
            - personal
    client:
        build:
            context: ./client
        environment:
            - API_HOST=api
            - NODE_ENV=production
        env_file:
            -   client/.env.local
        networks:
            - personal
        ports:
            - "80:8080"
networks:
    personal:
```

I have two .env files

```
.env
.env.production
```

and both are the same

```
NODE_ENV=production
API_HOST=api
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated...

----- Update -----

In the end I had tried many of the accepted answers suggestions however the issue was the routing. I had it set to `api` and not `v1` i.e `/v1/test`.

However I hope this post helps others with correct configuration.
The devil is in the details @masseyb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` inside the `client` service is the containers `localhost`, not your PC's `localhost` where you have the ports mapped.

`nginx` is trying to pass connections to `upstream { server localhost:8081; }` given your `API_HOST` environment variable, there is nothing in the `client` service listening on port `8081` hence "Connection refused".

You can update your `API_HOST` to e.g. `api` resulting in `upstream { server api:8081; }`, `api` will be resolved to the containers IP, and the connections will be passed to `<container_ip>:8081` instead of `localhost:8081` (preferred) OR you can run the `client` service on the `host` network and keep using `localhost`.

Comment: I am able to call the backend in the client container with `http://api:8081/v1/test` however axios still cannot get a response. I tried `"http://api:8081"`, `"http://api:8080"`, and `"http://localhost:8080"`. I added `api` to the `server_name` but I do not think that has any effect. Thank you very much for posting.

Comment: @Mike3355 the js code runs in the browser on your PC, the request is done from the browser running on your PC to the container - it needs to hit the `client` `nginx` service, and from your PC's PoV the service is exposed on port 80 (ref. your `docker-compose.yml` `services.client.port`), thus your baseUrl for the requests should be e.g. `http://localhost` (default port 80) if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I tired `http://localhost`.. This is very frustrating.. I will post when I figure it out. It has to be something small somewhere.

Comment: For future reference the remaining issue was that the vue.js requests were to `/v1/test` which didn't match `nginx`'s `location ~ ^/(api)/` regex, updating to `location ~ ^/(v1)/` does the trick. The devil is in the details, always.